# GRAILS 3 sql express: no driver

Tags: sql-server, grails, gradle, grails-3.0

I recently installed grails 3.1.x and tested it with mysql. All right.
When I moved similarly to MS express 2008 I found: **No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver.** 
I am not able to find a correct MS dependency with maven so I downloaded basic jdbc4.jar from Microsoft server, but GRAILS does not know I have it; so

- where should I put it to install it manually?
- Some on GRAILS 2.x say about lib folder but I tried it without success.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 5):

It is more gradle issue than grails. You must tell gradle where this driver is located. As it cannot be pulled from any maven repo it can be added as local file dependency. See the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies).

Add to build.gradle something like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile files('libs/jdbc4.jar')
  //... already added dependencies 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it! It is possible to use jtds driver, via Maven. So simply

- put `runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'` in build.gradle file
- and use correct syntax in Datasource like 
    `driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
      dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
      url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=db_name"
      username = "sa"
      password = "my_password"`

I am not sure dialect is mandatory. Of course it is important to manage properly configuration of DB express to have port 1433 static, not dynamic which is default, and default user SA with password authentication. But it works, after many research days!

Comment: This didn't work for me, but adding the jar to the lib folder and using @Piotr Chowaniec answer did work.

Comment: Do you mean that insertion in build.gradle was not enough to have the jar installed?

Comment: That's correct.  Putting `runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'` in build.gradle file did not work for me. I had to actually place the jar in folder in the project, which I called `{project_directory}/libs`; and then I added `compile files('libs/jdbc4.jar')` to the `dependencies` section of `build.gradle`.